# doctrine 2 querybuilder with set parameters not working

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, query-builder

this is my query:

public function getDetails($userid, $orderby, $sort){

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('u')
                ->from('\Entities\Users', 'u')
                ->where('u.userid= ?1')
                ->orderBy('u.?3', '?3')
                ->setParameter(1, $userid)
                ->setParameter(2, $orderby)
                ->setParameter(3, $sort)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

}
```

it keeps erroring: Message: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near '?3 DESC': Error: '?3' is not defined.

how do i get the orderby from the properties in that function to the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for dinamical build of DQL query. You'll have to code it by your own:

```
$sortBy = in_array($sortBy, array(...)) ? $sortBy : 'id';
$sortDir = $sortDir == 'ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

$this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ...
    ->orderBy('u.' . $sortBy, $sortDir)
```

Comment: Doctrine has so many painful shortcomings.  It is slow, complex, and yet pretty limited.  It is hard to see how this is better than straight php/sql stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You cant bind parameters to QueryBuilder, only to Query, so just swap lines, first get query out of builder, then fill it with parameters and get result.

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from('\Entities\Users', 'u')
            ->where('u.userid= ?1')
            ->orderBy('u.?3', '?3')
            ->orderBy('u.'.$orderBy, $sort)
            ->getQuery()
            ->setParameter(1, $userid)
            ->getResult();

}
```

In doctrine 2.4 its fixed, and you can bind parameters to QueryBuilder.

Update: i've missed moment with placeholder in field name, SQL do not support such constructions.