# Doctrine Querybuilder, binding Parameters

Tags: doctrine-orm

My Select function of my QueryManager:

```
/**
 * Führt eine SELECT - Query durch
 *
 * @param   $select = array( array(column, [...]), table, shortcut )
 *          $orderby = array(column, sorting-type)
 *          $where = array( array( column, value, type[or, and] ), [...] )
 *          $innerjoin = array( table, shortcut, condition )
 *          $pagination = array( page, limit )
 * 
 * @return array $data
 */
public function select($select,$orderby, $where, $innerjoin, $pagination)
{
    $qb = $this->conn->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($select[0])
        ->from($select[1], $select[2])
    ;

    if ($orderby) {
        $qb->orderBy($orderby);
    }

    if ($where) {
        foreach($where as $cond) {
            $x = 0;
            if ( key($cond) == 0 ) {
                $qb
                    ->where($cond[0] . ' = ?')
                    ->setParameter($x,$cond[1]);
            }
            elseif ( $cond[2] == 'and' ) {
                $qb
                    ->andWhere($cond[0] . ' = ?')
                    ->setParameter($x,$cond[1]);
            }
            elseif ( $cond[2] == 'and' ) {
                $qb
                    ->orWhere($cond[0] . ' = :' . $x)
                    ->setParameter($x,$cond[1]);
            }
            $x++;
        }
    }

    if ($innerjoin) {
        $qb->join($select[2],$innerjoin);
    }

    $this->sql = $qb->getSQL();

    $this->totalRowCount = count( $qb->execute() ) ;

    if ($pagination) {
        $max = $pagination[0] * $pagination[1];
        $first =  $max - $limit;

        $qb
            ->setFirstResult($first)
            ->setMaxResults($max)
        ;
    }

    $stmt = $qb->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

I don't know why, but in action, this function produces a select query without inserted values for the parameters:

```
/**
 * Lädt einen User nach dessen Username
 *
 * @param $username
 * @return User $user | null
 */
public function getUser($username)
{
    if($data = $this->select(array('*','users','u'), null, array( array('username',$username) ), null,null)) {
        return $user = $this->hydrate($data);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I didn't get a result, and the query is not setup correctly:

```
array(0) { }
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE username = ?
```

In my opinion the Builder doesn't supstitute my parameters with the provided values ...

I got the latest version of Doctrine DBAL (2.4) and this version should support this features!

Thanks for Help and Suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this Problem. I have readed here [doctrine 2 querybuilder with set parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775706/doctrine-2-querybuilder-with-set-parameters-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top) that:

> You cant bind parameters to QueryBuilder, only to Query

But im creating SQL conditions as collected AND & OR experssions in deep nested objects, and the toppest object creates the query object. So i cant create the query object before, i always return expression objects.

So i solved the problem with direct including the variable into the prepared variable's position.

```
$qb->where($cond[0] . '=' . $cond[1]);
```

And because i expect strings there i added hard coded quotes. This is not the desired way, but at the moment i dont know how to solve that in an other way with binding parameters to the **QueryBuilder** object.

```
$expr = $d_qb->expr()->between($t_c, "'" . $date_from . "'", "'" . $date_from . "'");
```

Other suggestions?

Following codes results:

```
$expr = $d_qb->expr()->between($t_c, ':from', ':to');
$d_qb->setParameter('from', 1);
$d_qb->setParameter('to', 1);
```

or

```
$expr = $d_qb->expr()->between($t_c, ':from', ':to');
$d_qb->setParameter(':from', 1);
$d_qb->setParameter(':to', 1);
```

Results:

```
e0_.created BETWEEN ? AND ?
```