# Doctrine Query->getSQL() doesn't output any parameter

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

In Symfony2 I got the next code in a custom repository function:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $any = "Jon";

    $qb->select('s')
        ->from('AppBundle:Student', 's');


    if ($criteria) {
        foreach ($criteria as $field => $value) {
            $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('s.' . $field, $value));
        }
    }

    $qb->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->like('s.firstname', ":any"),
            $qb->expr()->like('s.lastname', ":any"),
            $qb->expr()->like('s.dni', ":any"),
            $qb->expr()->like('s.email', ":any")
        )
    );
    if ($offset) {
        $qb->setFirstResult($offset);
    }
    if ($limit) {
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $query->setParameter('any',(string) $any);

    $logger->warning(__METHOD__ . ": " . json_encode($query->getSQL()));

    $result = $query->getResult();
```

But $result is always empty. Maybe because $query->getSQL() always returns:

```
"SELECT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.firstname AS firstname1, p0_.lastname AS lastname2, p0_.email AS email3, p0_.dni AS dni4, p0_.phonenumber AS phonenumber5, p0_.active AS active6, p0_.birthdate AS birthdate7, p0_.sex AS sex8, p0_.discr AS discr9 
FROM student s1_ INNER JOIN person p0_ ON s1_.id = p0_.id 
WHERE p0_.active = 1 AND (p0_.firstname LIKE ? OR p0_.lastname LIKE ? OR p0_.dni LIKE ? OR p0_.email LIKE ?) LIMIT 15"
```

The thing is, if I misspell the parameter name it throws an Exception, so the $query->setParameter line is executing. It's just... not working :S

**UPDATE 1:**

It was suggested that it might be caused by the same parameter being reused. I updated the code to:

```
 (...)
    $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->like('s.firstname', ":fn"),
                $qb->expr()->like('s.lastname', ":ln"),
                $qb->expr()->like('s.dni', ":dni"),
                $qb->expr()->like('s.email', ":email")
            )
        );
    (...)
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $query->setParameters(array('fn' => $any, 'ln' => $any, "dni" => $any, "email" => $any));
```

NO CHANGES. :<

**UPDATE 2:**

Tried

```
$qb->setParameters(array('fn' => $any, 'ln' => $any, "dni" => $any, "email" => $any));

$query = $qb->getQuery();

$logger->warning(__METHOD__ . ": " . json_encode($query->getSQL()));
```

...No changes.

**UPDATE 3:**

Debugging parameters as suggested:

Code:

```
$query = $qb->getQuery();

$parameters = $qb->getQuery()->getParameters()->toArray();
foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
        $logger->warning(__METHOD__ . ": Parameter -> ".json_encode($parameter->getName())." = ".json_encode($parameter->getValue()));
    }
$logger->warning(__METHOD__ . ": " . json_encode($query->getSQL()));
```

Log:

```
 app.WARNING: AppBundle\Entity\StudentRepository::findByAny: Parameter -> "fn" = "Jon" [] []
 app.WARNING: AppBundle\Entity\StudentRepository::findByAny: Parameter -> "ln" = "Jon" [] []
 app.WARNING: AppBundle\Entity\StudentRepository::findByAny: Parameter -> "dni" = "Jon" [] []
 app.WARNING: AppBundle\Entity\StudentRepository::findByAny: Parameter -> "email" = "Jon" [] []
 app.WARNING: AppBundle\Entity\StudentRepository::findByAny: "SELECT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.firstname AS firstname1, p0_.lastname AS lastname2, p0_.email AS email3, p0_.dni AS dni4, p0_.phonenumber AS phonenumber5, p0_.active AS active6, p0_.birthdate AS birthdate7, p0_.sex AS sex8, p0_.discr AS discr9 FROM student s1_ INNER JOIN person p0_ ON s1_.id = p0_.id WHERE p0_.active = 1 AND (p0_.firstname = ? OR p0_.lastname = ? OR p0_.dni = ? OR p0_.email = ?) LIMIT 15" [] []
```

Still no results, and the SQL still shows "?". Though I think I found the error...

Comment: And what happens when you use the setParameter() method to the queryBuilder and not the query ? Cause I've never seen it used like this

Comment: Also doesnt work. I actually had the parameter set in the queryBuilder but after some researching, the second answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775706/doctrine-2-querybuilder-with-set-parameters-not-working stated that it didn't work on builders prior to 2.4, so I changed it, without any luck... : /

Comment: You are setting your parameter after you call `getQuery()`. Try using `$qb->setParameter()` before you call `->getQuery()` and see what happens.

Comment: @Artamiel I'm setting the parameters after calling getQuery() because I'm setting the parameters **of** the query. Calling $qb->setParameters(...) before getQuery() (**Update 2**) makes no difference :<

Comment: That's strange. Try dumping `$qb->getQuery()->getParameters()` and see if there are any bound parameters to your query. If there are, you are simply not getting results and your query should be rewritten. If there are not, we will look for something else.

Comment: @Artamiel I did and they were bound. But it got me thinking of a new approach. Thank you very much. Your help was really... helpful. Appreciated. (Damn, my vocabulary is limited) ^^U

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a numeric parameter name and then call `setParameters` instead of `setParameter`.

```php
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->like('s.firstname', "?0"),
        $qb->expr()->like('s.lastname', "?1"),
        $qb->expr()->like('s.dni', "?2"),
        $qb->expr()->like('s.email', "?3")
    )
);

$qb->setParameters([
    'first name', 
    'last name', 
    'user dni', 
    'user.email@gmail.com'
]);
```

Another option could be:

```php
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->like('s.firstname', ":fn"),
        $qb->expr()->like('s.lastname', ":ln"),
        $qb->expr()->like('s.dni', ":dni"),
        $qb->expr()->like('s.email', ":email")
    )
)

$qb->setParameter('fn', 'first name');
$qb->setParameter('ln', 'last name');
$qb->setParameter('dni', 'user dni');
$qb->setParameter('email', 'user email');
```

**EDIT:** just checked, adding the same parameter it is allowed like mentioned by Artamiel.

Comment: ...really? How is that not allowed? D: 
That's bonkers!

Comment: Side note - having the same named parameter for multiple columns is allowed. Quite a lot of filters works this way actually. Imagine having single `keyword` field which should look in multiple columns. I myself am using approach like this as well.

Comment: Francesco, I tried to change it (see **UPDATE 1**) No luck. @Artamiel That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. To search for the same string in multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

...so I figured it out (with a lot of help from the comments, of course). It's simple but it got me for many hours. Don't you hate when that happens?

It wasn't working because when you set the parameters like

```
$qb->expr()->like('s.firstname', ":fn")
$qb->setParameters(array('fn' => $any));
```

you must manually include the % character:

```
    $any = "%Jon%";
```

instead of

```
    $any = "Jon";
```

which, of course, makes sense. You may only want the % character in one of the sides.

What DOESN'T make a lot of sense is that the **$query->getSQL() will still not show the parameters** (only "?" characters) even though the parameters are linked to the QueryBuilder and not the Query itself, so it's like: "What's the point?".

**Moral:** Dont trust Query->getSQL() for debugging purposes. Almost useless.

Special credit to user @Artamiel

Comment: Since we figured it out from our comments I want to add a note here as well. This is an expected behavior. Just because you told your `QueryBuilder` to use `LIKE` expression, it doesn't mean that it has to apply `%` characters to your string. Don't forget that there are many cases when `%` are not needed. You ask for `->like()` and that's what you get in your query.

Comment: @Artamiel I agree it's expected behaviour (that's why I said "makes sense" to my answer). But it can still be hard to figure out since it is barely documented and ->getSQL() doesn't output parameters, which I don't think is the expected (or rather, the *ideal*) behaviour. Also, getSQL() is not documented at all.

Comment: `getSQL()` should not print out any parameters whatsoever. That's the reason there is `getParameters()` method. With `getSQL() ` you get a final version of generated SQL which would later on be prepared to be executed (hint: `PDO prepared statement`), hence the reason why you get `?` instead of your bound parameters. Btw, everything w've done so far is available in your profiler (if you are on `dev` environment). Well, I believe this is enough info on the subject.

Comment: Note that binding parameters will not prevent wildcard (`_` and `%`) injections so you might need to apply addCSlashes to the value.